# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500

Tags: java, android

I am using volley for POST method to server. I am sending two parametars and I am getting this Unexpected response code 500.

Here is `JsonObjectReguest` code:

[final String URL](http://maps.b1.finki.ukim.mk/MapController/save)

```
            JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                }
            }){
                protected HashMap<String, String> getParams() {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("cid", String.valueOf(id));
                    params.put("positions", string);

                    return params;
                }
                @Override
                public HashMap<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return headers;
                }
            };


            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
        }
```

Here is my logcat:

> 04-08 02:44:05.110  32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample
>   I/System.out﹕ propertyValue:true 04-08 02:44:05.114 
>   32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample I/System.out﹕ [socket][3]
>   connection
>   maps.b1.finki.ukim.mk/194.149.138.7:80;LocalPort=45144(2500) 04-08
>   02:44:05.115  32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample I/System.out﹕
>   [CDS]connect[maps.b1.finki.ukim.mk/194.149.138.7:80] tm:2 04-08
>   02:44:05.116  32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample D/Posix﹕
>   [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.bukic.postexample :80 04-08
>   02:44:05.189  32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample I/System.out﹕
>   [socket][/192.168.1.100:45144] connected 04-08 02:44:05.189 
>   32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample I/System.out﹕ [CDS]rx
>   timeout:2500 04-08 02:44:05.302 
>   32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample I/System.out﹕ Shutdown rx/tx
>   04-08 02:44:05.303  32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample
>   I/System.out﹕ [CDS]close[45144] 04-08 02:44:05.304 
>   32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample I/System.out﹕ Shutdown rx/tx
>   04-08 02:44:05.305  32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample
>   I/System.out﹕ Shutdown rx/tx 04-08 02:44:05.307 
>   32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample I/System.out﹕ close
>   [socket][/0.0.0.0:45144] 04-08 02:44:05.309 
>   32385-32511/com.example.bukic.postexample E/Volley﹕ [3280]
>   BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for
>   http://maps.b1.finki.ukim.mk/MapController/save 04-08 02:44:05.313 
>   32385-32385/com.example.bukic.postexample E/Volley﹕ [1](http://maps.b1.finki.ukim.mk/MapController/save)
>   2.onErrorResponse: Error:

Comment: 500 means there is an internal error in server. Check your network and http header&body.

Answer (score 0):

![One of params is **cid**][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY1R5.jpg one of params is cid

![One of params is **cId**][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0AHG.jpg one of params is cId instead of cid

I recommend you a extension of chrome named **Postman**. We can send http request and verify the result by using it and it is very useful.

Comment: Hm...i change cid in cld in my code and run app,but i still get this BasicNetwork.performRequest...